# How to check checkbox base on value

Tags: angular

**My thought**
I received value "Yes" and "No" . I want to check checkbox if i received "Yes"  and uncheck checkbox when i received "No"

**Data received**

```
{
  "expires_in": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "patientId": 2143,
      "substanceAbuseAlcohol": "No",
      "substanceAbuseMarijuana": "Yes",
}]}
```

**Code that i tried**
this code always check the checkbox even if i received Yes or No. I wanted to check only when received data is Yes from Api

```
 <section class="pleft ptop">
              <mat-checkbox color="primary"
              (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue(
                $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')" 
                checked="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol')==='Yes'" 
               >Alcohol</mat-checkbox><br>
            
              <mat-checkbox (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseMarijuana').setValue(
                $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
                checked="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseMarijuana')==='Yes'"  color="primary" >Marijuana</mat-checkbox><br>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Other</mat-label>
                <input type="other" matInput formControlName="substanceAbuseOther" 
                placeholder="">
              </mat-form-field>
          </section>
```

**form**

```
 this.patientPastHistoryForm = new FormGroup({
      patientId: new FormControl(this.clientId),
      substanceAbuseAlcohol: new FormControl('No'),
      substanceAbuseMarijuana: new FormControl('No'),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to check checkbox base on data received from api. Example if i received "Yes" than i want to check the checkbox and if i received "No" than i want to uncheck the checkbox

Comment: should be `[checked]=`

Comment: there is error when i Used [checked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples#checkbox-configurable) from the Angular Material documentation, I suggest you to use `[(ngModel)]` to control the state of your checkboxes.

I created a Stackblitz demo to show you how to use it: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvkrxx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

In your case, when you receive your data, please update the checked variable in the class with your desired value, lets say `'Yes'` is `true` and `'No'` is `false`, and your checkbox will be updated.